# Representations are not adapted to screen on Safari/Explorer

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js, mpeg-dash, dash.js

By passing to high sierra I got an issue about the visualization of Mpeg-Dash adaptive streaming:

The representations are not adapted to the screen, the green screen appears around the representations,

[image]

Only the largest representation is correctly displayed.

This happen on Safari of high Sierra but In previous versions OSX there was not issues, I found that the problem also happens on Explorer but it never happens on Chrome

I try to update video.min.js , dash.all.min.js and videojs-dash.min.js
but the problem remains.

The temporary link is [allibrante.com](https://www.allibrante.com)

Please is there anyone who can help me understand where the mistake is?

Comment: It may be related to a fullscreen bug that people have reported: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8087796

Comment: Thanks for support Mick, i fix it by adding" bs-switching no" flag on MP4Box